# How to reference a belongs_to association in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

```
#!ruby
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
end

@cars = Car.where(:user_id => current_user.id).limit(10)
```

I want to create a scope, how can I use the association :user in the scope?

(rails3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your model:

```
scope :foo, lambda {|u| where( :user_id => u ).limit(10) }
```

...which you can then call from your controller with:

```
Car.foo(current_user)
```

Comment: lambda syntax works...I kinda feel like it's a bit of a pre-arel hack and there are so many more options now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Car.join(:user).where(:user_id => current_user.id).limit(10)
```

Update:

in your model

```
def self.with_user(user)
  join(:user).where(:user_id => user.id)
end
```

in your controller

```
Car.with_user(current_user).limit(10)
```

Comment: That's not a scope, and wouldn't work anyway because `current_user` won't be valid in the model.

Comment: I'd define a method on the Car class, if that's a possibility: def self.with_user(current_user) with something like the above and in your controller: Car.with_user(current_user).limit(10).

Comment: edited the answer so I could format things...hope that helps?

Comment: Also, there's no need to do the `join` - it's a `belongs_to` so the fkey is right there in the `cars` table.